# Is it OK to mix and distribute data licensed under CC0 and Public Domain?

Tags: public-domain

I would like to create an style-unified collection of cartographic symbols - mainly for use with free SW like QGIS.

I would like to use (probably modify) some already prepared ones from various CC0 licensed sources like [SJJB icons](http://www.sjjb.co.uk/mapicons/introduction) or [Maki icons](https://www.mapbox.com/maki-icons/) but also some from [OpenClipart Library](https://openclipart.org/share)

Am I right if I think that I can freely mix and modify distributed content without need to cite sources for particular icons? I plan to keep the CC0 1.0 Universal (CC0 1.0) Public Domain Dedication license even for my original additional icons to not to restrict use in any way and I plan to add something like "*Some icons are from source 1), some from source 2)*" etc. - just to be fair.

Is it OK?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are licensed under CC0 it is impossible to infringe their copyright.

You have the same rights as if they were public domain due to age.